# How do I resolve the AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute in Google API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-admin-sdk

For full context I'm a newbie in scripting. I'm trying to get a full list of users from Google Admin using Google's API, but I'm struggling to even get passed the `build()` section of it. Whatever I tag onto `service` it just does not have that attribute, except for `close()`

My end goal is to pretty much get a full list of users, user aliases, and group names so I can check if they're already existing before creating/assigning one. Unfortunately, I'm stuck at this hurdle.

API I'm trying to use: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory

Code:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/env python3

import json
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = os.get.environ('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE')

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

Here is the Error I keep running into if I were to just attempt to execute it with `service.execute()`:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
        service.execute()
    AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

If I were to run it without anything, just after the `service = ...` line, it does not spit out an error, so I'm assuming the service account file is correct.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include all relevant code and the full traceback error.

Comment: ```googleapiclient.discovery.build()``` returns a Resource object, which doesn't have an ```execute``` method.  Please read https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Hi @ewong! Thanks for responding! That's the whole code, I'm just getting started with it. Also, that's the full traceback error from me running `$python test.py` What object am I looking for? The link you sent me do something similar with `document = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()` where can I find what functions I can call from `service`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `service` variable, returned by [build](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build), corresponds to the [class Resource](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery.Resource-class.html).

This class can be used to interact with the API you specified when building the service. Depending on those parameters, the `service` will have specific API methods at its disposal, but `execute()` is not one of them.

Since you are building the service for [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory), these will be the corresponding methods for interacting with this API:

- [Admin Directory API > Instance Methods](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/index.html)

For example, if you wanted to call [Users: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) in order to list all users in your domain, you would do the following:

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=getCreds())
response = service.users().list(domain="YOUR_DOMAIN").execute()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for these resources and example code, @lamblichus ! This is exactly what I was having trouble looking for. Can I then convert `response` to JSON or is it automatically JSON?

Comment: @hyphalos This is the response body you'll get: [ref](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#response). For example, you would access the email address of the first user by doing the following: `response["users"][0]["primaryEmail"]`.

Comment: @lamblichus , thanks so much! This makes sense to me now and I can finally work on it. I might just use the `get` method as it searches both primary and alias emails, wouldn't of found that method without you sourcing the docs. Much appreciated! I accepted your answer.

Comment: @hyphalos You're welcome! Glad your issue was solved.